# Paragraphs with a vertical bar on the left, but starting *after* the first line of text

Tags: paragraphs

I'd like to write paragraphs (e.g. definitions, theorems etc.) having the following appearance: there's a vertical bar to the left of the entire paragraph, *except* the first line of text. Furthermore, the entire paragraph is indented to compensate, excepting the first line.

Any ideas how this effect can be achieved?

Comment: do you need to allow page breaking mid-paragraph (which makes it much harder)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fiddle with the margins and rule widths with `mdframed` options, but basically something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\addtolength\textheight{-20\baselineskip}
\setlength\textwidth{6cm}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\def\a{One two three four five six.}
\def\b{Red yellow blue green black white. }
\def\c{\a\a\b\b\a\a}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\c

\b\c

\begin{mdframed}[topline=false,rightline=false,bottomline=false]
\hspace*{-\parindent}%
\rlap{\smash{\colorbox{white}{\strut\hspace{\parindent}}}}%
\c\c\c\c\c\c
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```